# Remove Zone from hot water radiant heating system

Tags: electrical, plumbing, hot-water, radiant-heating

I want to remove a zone from my hot water heating system.  The zone has an an electric zone valve wired to my panel and to the thermostat.  When set the thermostat to turn up the heat, it closes a circuit that causes the zone valve to switch on a motor that open the valve for that zone allowing heat through the piping.

On the return side of the piping, there is a manual valve.  I was wondering what the process is for disconnecting a zone, draining the water from that part so I can completely remove that zone and it's piping.

Edit:  I am doing this because I want to replace a line of pipe that is deteriorating and move one of the radiators.  I also want to keep the other zones operational so the rest of my house has heat.  During this time I will also be doing some work on the interior, so I have to remove and move some radiators and walls.  That is why I want the other zones to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the boiler, turn off the pump, turn off the water pressure to the boiler.  Cut and cap the return and supply for that zone.

Remove the zone value wiring.

Re-pressurize and bleed the system, turn it back on.

Comment: The thing is, I want the other zones to work while I am doing this.  My upstairs still needs heat.

Comment: @Allan Yes, you were clear about that. This answer's first bullet directs you to cut and cap the return and supply _for that zone_. This leaves the other zones' plumbing intact. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I just finished this job and thought I would mention that I ended up draining the whole system before doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend **against** a permanent disconnection.  Pull the electrical leads from the zone valve so it remains closed at all times.  The manual valve is intended (I suspect) to allow bleeding a given zone, remove bubbles, etc.  Close or open as you desire.

Someday in the future you or a subsequent tenant may want that zone to go 'live' again.

Comment: I will update my post, but I have to replace the piping which is why I want to 'remove' the zone.  I want to work on it with out worrying about the valve opening when the pipe is disconnected

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if all the zones are plumbed in parallel — that is, all the zones connect to a single manifold. If so, disconnecting one zone downstream from the manifold won't disconnect or prevent water flow through other zones.

Your steps are:

- Turn off boiler
- Turn off pump
- Turn off water feed input to entire
  system
- Cut and cap the supply and return lines that feed and return
  from the zone you wish to disconnect
- Turn on water feed input to
  entire system
- Turn on pump
- Turn on boiler